# Difference Between Distinct Count() and Count(Distinct)

Tags: mysql

I have a Table Like so

| user_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | false |
| 2 | true |

Im Trying to Find the distinct count user_id where They are true and where they are false.

the query i have now is

```
SELECT
    COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN `status` = 'true' THEN 1 END ) AS `trues`,
    COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN `status` = 'false' THEN 1 END ) AS `false`,
FROM table
```

What is the difference between just removing Distinct from count and doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT( CASE WHEN `status` = 'true' THEN 1 END ) AS `trues`,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN `status` = 'false' THEN 1 END ) AS `false`,
FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

From the MySQL docs...

[`count`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)

> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement.

[`count(distinct)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

For example, if you have 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, null `count` will count 1,1,1,2,3 for 5 and `count(distinct)` will count 1,2,3 for 3.

[`select distinct`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

> DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

The key difference between `select distinct count()` and `select count(distinct)` is with `select count(distinct)` the distinct filter happens *while counting*, with `select distinct count()` the distinct filter happens *after counting*.

---

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN `status` = 'true' THEN 1 END ) AS `trues`,
    COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN `status` = 'false' THEN 1 END ) AS `false`
FROM table;
```

This will always be 1 or 0.

The case statements will always result in 1 or null, so the results can only be something like 1,1,null,1,null. There's only 1 distinct non-null value to count, so the result is 1. If there's no matches it's null, null, null, there's no distinct non-null values so the result is 0.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT( CASE WHEN `status` = 'true' THEN 1 END ) AS `trues`,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN `status` = 'false' THEN 1 END ) AS `false`,
FROM table
```

Here, because there is a single row, the distinct has no effect; there's only one row and it's always going to be distinct.

But if there were multiple rows, perhaps because there's a group by, it would only return those results which are distinct. For example, let's say without the distinct we get...

```
trues  false
------------
1      1
1      1
1      2
2      2
2      2
```

Then `select distinct` will only return those rows which are distinct.

```
trues  false
------------
1      1
1      2
2      2
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=154da56d03e1da7ed68c8b0062580395).

Comment: TL;DR: distinct in the two places does very different things; *neither* seems desirable for this query

Comment: @ysth Yes. I can think of one use, if you want to check for the existence of true and false values. But that might be better done with [`any`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp) to avoid having to scan the whole table.